.NET 8 Minimal API return JSON string as Json without first deserialize into an object
If I have a string (which is already in JSON format) say
string JsonStr = "{ 'A': 123 }";

My API is
public JsonResult OnGetRetrieve()
{
    string JsonStr = "{ 'A': 123 }";
    return new JsonResult(JsonStr);  // This will return the Json as a string
}

If I wish to return as a Json object, I need to
return new JsonResult(JsonConvert.Deserialize(JsonStr));

I am sure there is a better way than this.
Thanks in advance.

Is it Minimal APIs or Controllers?

@GuruStron Minimal APIs

Have you checked the suggested answer does it work for you?

If you have a JSON string and you want to return it as JSON you can use Content helper methods. For example for minimal APIs with Results.Content (or TypedResults.Content):
return Results.Content(JsonStr); 

or in controllers:
return this.Content(JsonStr);

Possibly you will need to specify the contentType parameter (application/json).
